# Ionic --live-reload not running app on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, livereload

I can't see my ionic app on my phone when using the `--live-reload` parameter.

I am using Windows 8.1 and a connected Nexus 5 Android device. The app is the sample *sidemenu* app created with `ionic start demo sidemenu`.

---

When I run `ionic run --live-reload`, I first get presented by a list of possible IP addresses:

```
Multiple addresses available.
Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:
Note that the emulator/device must be able to access the given IP address
 1) 192.168.0.109 (Wi-Fi)
 2) 192.168.159.1 (VMware Network Adapter VMnet1)
 3) 192.168.174.1 (VMware Network Adapter VMnet8)
 4) 192.168.56.1 (VirtualBox Host-Only Network)
```

I choose option 1 - this is the IP address of my development PC, that is hosting the ionic server.

---

Ionic confirms this selection, and confirms it is serving to the ports as below:

```
Selected address: 192.168.0.109
Running live reload server: http://192.168.0.109:35729
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Running dev server: http://192.168.0.109:8100
```

I confirmed that it is serving the page by opening Chrome on my PC and navigating to http://192.168.0.109:8100

---

When the app runs on the Android device, it first displays the splash screen, then shows the webview with the error:

```
Web page not available
The Web page at http://192.168.0.109:8100/ could not be loaded as:

net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

---

This has also been reported on the Ionic forums:

- [Ionic Forums - Livereload error: Webpage not available](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/livereload-error-webpage-not-available/21161)

---

As far as I can tell, I have opened up TCP ports 35729 & 8100 on my Windows machine (using Control Panel - Firewall settings).

**What must I configure so that I can see my Ionic app on my device?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above configuration was all correct.

The ports needed to be open in Windows Firewall - but the missing step was requiring a reboot after updating the Firewall settings.

After a reboot, everything is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks. In Windows 10 for ionic cordova run android --device -l -c, opening the port 8100 solves this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Likely not the issue for most people, but for me it was because I was running a VPN on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

Easy, you can use this command in cmd and this is work well :

```
ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are facing a CORS issue.

Install & configure [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) shall correct your issue

Comment: useful info for generic issues of this kind. Good to know for someone coming from native apps over to hybrid apps.

Answer (score 2):

**What worked for me** (with no changes to any project config files or to my firewall settings):

```
$ ionic cordova run android -c -l --address=10.0.0.2 (use your local IP address here)
```

**My setup:**

- My Android phone (running Android 7.1.1) is connected via usb cable
  to my Windows desktop computer.
- The address used is the local IP address for the desktop computer,
  which I got from [www.whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-local-ip-address)

All the commands I used to get livereload working on my Android phone with a new ionic 3 project:

```
$ ionic start testLivereloadProject1 tabs
$ cd testLivereloadProject1
$ ionic cordova platform add android
$ ionic cordova run android -c -l --address=10.0.0.2
```

(-c is console, -l is livereload)

Note: It was initially very slow loading onto the phone (the splash screen went by, then it was solid white for a while), but once it loaded, the livereload worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm way late to this but my `config.xml` generated the following line somewhere in my build process:

`<content src="http://10.0.0.25:8100" original-src="index.html"/>`

I fixed it by changing it back to `<content  original-src="index.html"/>`    (without the `src="http://10.0.0.25:8100"`)

Comment: How come everytime I remove the src="https://10.0.0.25:8100", it gets generated again when I run android?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me, I checked for which network was my phone connected and which network my laptop was connected. Since they were different, I made them connect to the same network and it resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CLI version with **ionic info**.

Live-reload stopped working for me as the OP described, I had to revert to 4.12.0 in order to get it up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to struggle with the firewall, use the host option:

`ionic capacitor run android -l --host=172.20.10.10`